# Initiate a class in js after 3 seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mobile

I have a mobile site that I would like to have the nav that is revealed via css3 transition to  close after 3 seconds. The transition is all in css no js with a class on an anchor tag that triggers the nav to close. (the code is example: `a href="#" class="close_nav"`). The class close_nav is just set to display: none

How do I get it to close after 3 seconds?

Comment: see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition-duration

Comment: [setTimeout()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setTimeout)

Answer (score 2):

In order to initiate some javascript after a delay, use setTimeout().

Like so:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    var d = document.getElementById("your element");
    d.className = "close_nav";
},3000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Set a delay of 3 seconds on the animation in the css; http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-delay.asp

It may help to add

```
transition-delay: 3s;
```

to the CSS animation along with browser prefixes

Comment: +1 While an external link to show more detail is often handy, make the core point part of your answer so it's preserved on SO to save future visitors a click or two.

Comment: It can also be useful for people to self-educate, but I agree with your point